# SVG to Java's Path2d parser

Tags: java, svg

Is there an application to convert a svg drawing to Java's Path2d?

Is this method more efficient than using any SVG to Java toolkit? (with efficiency i refer to runtime speed).

Thanks.

Comment: SVG drawings can be a lot more complex than `Path2D` objects. Those objects don't even represent color. And we're not even talking about line-style, fill-style, effects, ... here.

Comment: You can define all those values, color, line style, etc. I'm sure you knew that. But what i think you meant is that those parameters are not included in the Path2D, only the shape vectors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to convert SVG path syntax to an AWT path object, you can use [Batik](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/)'s [`PathParser`](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/javadoc/org/apache/batik/parser/PathParser.html) class in conjunction with an [`AWTPathProducer`](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/javadoc/org/apache/batik/parser/AWTPathProducer.html).  That will generate an [`ExtendedGeneralPath`](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/javadoc/org/apache/batik/ext/awt/geom/ExtendedGeneralPath.html), which isn't a `Path2D` but it does implement `Shape`.